# mysql_fdw input syntax error

Tags: postgresql, bytea, foreign-data-wrapper

I am implementing mysql_fdw in PostgreSQL (9.4.4). I have created foreign table and they are working fine except for one thing: 
For some of the rows in column idvisitor with datatype bytea, it is throwing the following error

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea SQL state: 22P02

Example:
A table visits with two columns: id SERIAL, idvisitor bytea
Thousand rows with id from 1 to 1000

- SELECT * FROM visits; #ERROR
- SELECT * FROM visits WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 900; # NO ERROR
- SELECT * FROM visits WHERE id = 901; #ERROR
- SELECT * FROM visits WHERE id BETWEEN 902 AND 1000; # NO ERROR
- SELECT id FROM visits WHERE id=901; # NO ERROR

Proceeding like this, I could identify rows which are triggering the error. If I execute the same query in MySQL, it executes silently without throwing any error.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `bytea` data type. What is the MySQL data type you are mapping? `VARBINARY`?

Comment: Its binary(8) in MySQL table, mapped to bytea in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Seems like `mysql_fdw` needs a format conversion function for `binary` to support this. MySQL's `binary` representation is different to the representation PostgreSQL expects for `bytea`.

Comment: Could you please guide me to write this format conversion function? How to integrate it with mysql_fdw?

Comment: It'll be a modification to the mysql_fdw C code, if I'm right about what the problem is. I haven't done anything with mysql_fdw, so I can't really give much advice there. Consider filing a bug at https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/issues, including the MySQL table definition, the PostgreSQL foreign table definition, the problem data rows, etc.